# Fun depending on order of subs and values in accumarray

Tags: matlab, grouping, accumulate, accumarray

In [`accumarray()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) the first note about 'subs', first appeared in the MATLAB [R14sp3 docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R14sp3/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html#1047793), says:

> **Note**   If the subscripts in subs are not sorted, fun should not depend on the order of the values in its input data.

It is not clear to me what is considered to be sorted. Suppose:

```
subs = [1 1
        2 1
        1 2
        2 2];
```

1. shall `subs` be sorted in the sense `issorted(subs,'rows')`, or ...
2. in the **[linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511)** sense, i.e. `issorted(sub2ind([2 2],subs(:,1), subs(:,2)))`

I would like to rely on:

```
accumarray(subs,val,[], @(x) x(end))
```

If somebody could also provide examples/tests from older releases (to check for backward compatibility) where e.g. 1) is false while 2) is true, that would be great.

PS. I am mostly not interested in alternatives to `accumarray`, unless very succinct and using the same `subs` and `val`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I did some tests, and I think that "sorted" in the [quote](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#zmw57dd0e4423) is meant in the **[linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511)** sense. (I'm on R2013a if that matters)

To understand how `accumarray` calls the specified function, I'll use the [trick](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#f78-1048749) of grouping the values into a cellarray by specifying `fun = @(x) {x}` as the function to be applied.

### 1) 1D indices

First lets create some subscripts and values

```
N = 10; sz = 4;
subs = randi([1 sz], [N 1]);
vals = (1:N)'*100;
```

Now we call ACCUMARRAY on the non-sorted indices (multiple times)

```
C = cell(5,1);
for i=1:5
    C{i} = accumarray(subs, vals, [], @(x){x});
end
```

The order of the values passed to the function is arbitrary but still consistent across the multiple runs:

```
>> assert(isequal(C{:}))
>> celldisp(C{1})
ans{1} =
   800
   900
   700
ans{2} =
   300
ans{3} =
        1000
         200
         100
ans{4} =
   400
   600
   500
```

This is why the documentation warns you that `fun` should not depend on the order of the values passed to it.

Now if we sort the subscripts beforehand:

```
[~,ord] = sort(subs);
C = cell(5,1);
for i=1:5
    C{i} = accumarray(subs(ord), vals(ord), [], @(x){x});
end
assert(isequal(C{:}))
celldisp(C{1})
```

we will see that the values are passed to the function sorted themselves:

```
ans{1} =
   700
   800
   900
ans{2} =
   300
ans{3} =
         100
         200
        1000
ans{4} =
   400
   500
   600
```

### 2) 2D indices

I've tried the same thing in the case of 2D subscript indices. First we start with random data:

```
%# some 2d subscripts and corresponding values
N = 10; sz = 2;
subs = randi([1 sz], [N 2]);
vals = (1:N)*100;
```

- Here is the case for non-sorted indices:

  ```
  C = cell(5,1);
  for i=1:5
      C{i} = accumarray(subs, vals, [], @(x){x});
  end
  assert(isequal(C{:}))
  celldisp(C{1})
  ```
- Here is when I tried ["sorting by rows"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

  ```
  [~,ord] = sortrows(subs, [1 2]);
  C = cell(5,1);
  for i=1:5
      C{i} = accumarray(subs(ord,:), vals(ord), [], @(x){x});
  end
  assert(isequal(C{:}))
  celldisp(C{1})
  ```
- And finally here is when we sort by ["linear index"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

  ```
  [~,ord] = sort(sub2ind([sz sz], subs(:,1), subs(:,2)));
  C = cell(5,1);
  for i=1:5
      C{i} = accumarray(subs(ord,:), vals(ord), [], @(x){x});
  end
  assert(isequal(C{:}))
  celldisp(C{1})
  ```

I'll omit the long output, and report that only in the last case that the values were passed to the function *ordered*. So I conclude that the "sorted" criteria is based on the linear indices.

```
ans{1,1} =
     []
ans{2,1} =
   200
   600
   700
ans{1,2} =
         100
         300
         400
         500
        1000
ans{2,2} =
   800
   900
```

---

### Bonus:

Try using the following function instead:

```
function out = fun(x)
    out = {x};
    disp('[')
    disp(x)
    disp(']')
end
```

you'll see that the function is called in an unpredictable way, even with some duplication! You might have to increase the size of the data to see such behavior...

---

As far as backward compatibility goes, the documentation mentions this note all the way back in MATLAB [R14sp3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R14sp3/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html#1047793) but not [R14sp2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R14sp2/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html). Given the fact that it's been documented since [2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Release_history), I'd say it is safe to rely on this feature (I doubt anyone using such old versions expects new code to just work anyway!)

Comment: + 1 Great news for me! Although I would really like to see if somebody can run your testing suite on older versions to check for backward compatibility (could you make the 'linear indexing' in the first sentence bold?)

Comment: Subs in linear indexing sense also on R14sp3. Tested with: `N = 1000; sz = 2;
subs = [ceil(N/10.*rand(N,1)) ceil(sz.*rand(N,1))];
vals = (1:N)*100;
[ord,ord] = sort(sub2ind([N sz], subs(:,1), subs(:,2)));
C = cell(5,1);
for i=1:5
    C{i} = accumarray(subs(ord,:), vals(ord), [], @(x){x});
end
isequal(C{:})
all(cellfun(@issorted,C{1}))`

Comment: Nice. You must really care about backward compatibility! If I were you, I would check test the version of MATLAB in my code and error out if its too old for me test :)