# MatLab accumarray unexpectedly changing ordering

Tags: matlab, grouping, accumulate, accumarray

As long as I understood accumarray, it means "Making the nth row of the output: 1) find n in sub. 2) if n is in m1, m2, m3 th element in sub, 3) apply the function to m1,m2,m3 th element of val 4) that's the nth row of the output"

Am I wrong somewhere?

I ran the following code.

```
A = [2 10 13 ; 1 11 14; 1 12 10]
[U,ix,iu]= unique(A(:,1))
vals = reshape(A(:, 2:end).', [], 1)
subs = reshape(iu(:, ones(size(A, 2)-1,1)).', [], 1)
r2 = accumarray(subs, vals', [], @(x){x'})
r2{1}
r2{2}
```

A =

```
 2    10    13
 1    11    14
 1    12    10
```

U =

```
 1
 2
```

ix =

```
 3
 1
```

iu =

```
 2
 1
 1
```

vals =

```
10
13
11
14
12
10
```

subs =

```
 2
 2
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

r2 =

```
[1x4 double]
[1x2 double]
```

ans =

```
12    11    14    10
```

ans =

```
13    10
```

=========================

But I expected `r{1} = 11 14 12 10`, and `r{2} = 10 13`.

Why did accumarray suddenly changed the ordering?

How can I get the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation of accumarray](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) says:

> **Note**   If the subscripts in `subs` are not sorted, `fun` should not depend
>   on the order of the values in its input data.

And your `subs` is not sorted (at least not in ascending order). If you rewrite the code so that `subs` is sorted and `vals` is also rearranged accordingly you get the desired result:

```
A = [2 10 13 ; 1 11 14; 1 12 10]
[U,ix,iu]= unique(A(:,1))
vals = reshape(A(:, 2:end).', [], 1)
subs = reshape(iu(:, ones(size(A, 2)-1,1)).', [], 1)
[subs_sorted, I] = sort(subs);
r2 = accumarray(subs_sorted, vals(I)', [], @(x){x'})
r2{1}
r2{2}
```

And running this code returns:

```
ans =
    11    14    12    10
ans =
    10    13
```

Comment: Where sorted is meant in the [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) sense if you have multiple-column `subs`.

For details see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536558/) I recently asked.

Comment: @Mohsen_Nosratinia  Thank you! This works. I will vote for your answer once I reach enough reputation.

Comment: @LuisMendo You have become the please-_accept_-the-accepted-answer police, and I like it!