# Avoid loops in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, while-loop

I am limited in the use of cycles in matlab and I have one task. I have the matrix `2xn` with numbers and cell array `1xn`. Each element in the first row point to a position of the array. I want to add every number from the second row of matrix to cell, which is pointed by corresponding number in the first row. In addition, I want the cells to be strings.

Let me clarify with example:

`A = [[1 4 3 3 1 4 2], [7 4 3 5 6 5 4]]`

I want to get array of cells: `{'76', '4', '35', '45'}`

How can I do this without using a `for` or `while` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = [1 4 3 3 1 4 2; 7 4 3 5 6 5 4]; %// data: 2 x n array
[~, ~, ii] = unique(A(1,:));
R = accumarray(ii(:),A(2,:),[],@(v) {fliplr(regexprep(num2str(v(:).'),'\s',''))}).';
```

The second line (`unique`) is used to remove possible gaps in first row. Otherwise those gaps would translate to the result of `accumarray`, which would then take up more memory uselessly.

The third line (`accumarray`) aggregates all values of second row of `A` that have the same value in the first row. The aggregation is done by the anonymous function, which converts numbers to string (`num2str`), removes spaces (`regexprep`), and changes orientation (`fliplr` and `.'`) to match the desired output format.

*EDIT:*

Thanks to @chappjc's suggestion, the third line can be simplified to

```
R = accumarray(ii(:),A(2,:),[],@(v) {fliplr(num2str(v(:).','%d'))}).';
```

Comment: how do you come up with such complicated expressions :P?

Comment: @Parag :-) I've added some explanations

Comment: Its not about how complicated it is... its about how fast you came up with it :).

Comment: You can do without `regexprep` because `num2str` has a format specifier, which does not produce spaces: `num2str([7 6],'%d')`.  Or you could use `sprintf('%d',[7 6])`

Comment: @chappjc Nice! Those spaces were annoying. BTW, I just found out (working in this answer) that `accumarray` can return cells, which makes it even more powerful!

Comment: I think you just [forgot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17775147/2778484)! :) But, agreed, it does open lots of fun doors!

Comment: @chappjc Hey, you're right! I don't even remenber having seen some of the comments in that Q&A (Was it really me who answered??)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, by just pointing at [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html), [cell indexing](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) and [array indexing](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html) I was arrogant. So, I try to make it up by actually using some of those in a more constructive solution:

```
%// Using array-indexing to find all matches with the current index in the first row, 
%// then print their counterpart(s) into strings
fun = @(ii) sprintf('%d', A(2, A(1, :) == ii));  
%// The following could also be 1:size(A, 2) or unique(A(1, :)) depending on the 
%// general form of your problem.
range = min(A(1, :)) : max(A(1, :));   
%// Using arrayfun to loop over all values in the first row
R = arrayfun(fun, range, 'UniformOutput', false)
```