# Create Non Zero elements of Matrix in vector form in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a Matrix of size M by N in which each row has some zero entries. I want to create M row vectors such that each of the vector contains the non zero elements of each row. For example if I have the following Matrix

```
A=[0 0 0 5;0 0 4 6;0 1 2 3;9 10 2 3]
```

I want four different row vectors of the following form

```
 [5]
 [4 6]
 [1 2 3]
 [9 10 2 3]
```

Comment: You can construct the wanted matrices by going through the original matrix in a for loop, checking if the element is <>0 and saving the thus selected numbers in vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) using an anonymous function as fourth input argument. To make sure that the results are in the same order as in `A`, the grouping values used as first input [should be sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17774015/2586922). This requires using (a linearized version of) `A` transposed as second input.

```
ind = repmat((1:size(A,2)).',1,size(A,2)).';
B = A.';
result = accumarray(ind(:), B(:), [], @(x){nonzeros(x).'});
```

With `A = [0 0 0 5; 0 0 4 6; 0 1 2 3; 9 10 2 3];` this gives

```
result{1} =
     5
result{2} =
     4     6
result{3} =
     1     2     3
result{4} =
     9    10     2     3
```

Comment: Man I love `accumarray`!

Comment: @Suever You're not alone in that :-) http://stackoverflow.com/users/2778484/chappjc

Answer (score 1):

Since Matlab doesn't support non-rectangular `double` arrays, you'll want to settle on a `cell` array.  One quick way to get the desired output is to combine [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) with [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
nonZeroVectors = arrayfun(@(k) A(k,A(k,:)~=0),1:size(A,1),'UniformOutput',false);
```

I used the ([`'UniformOutput'`,`false`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html#namevaluepairarguments)) name-value pair for the reasons indicated in the documentation (I'll note that the pair (`'uni'`,`0`) also works, but I prefer verbosity).  This input produces a cell array with the entries

```
>> nonZerosVectors{:}
ans =
     5
ans =
     4     6
ans =
     1     2     3
ans =
     9    10     2     3
```