# Matlab: extract values from vector A, based on values in vector B

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
A = [5    10    16    22    28    32    36    44    49    56]
B = [2     1     1     2     1     2     1     2     2     2]
```

How to get this?

```
C1 = [10 16 28 36]
C2 = [5 22 32 44 49 56]
```

`C1` needs to get the values from `A`, only in the positions in which `B` is `1`
`C2` needs to get the values from `A`, only in the positions in which `B` is `2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this this way :

```
C1 = A(B==1);
C2 = A(B==2);
```

`B==1` gives a logical array :     `[ 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 ]`.

`A(logicalArray)` returns elements for which the value of `logicalArray` is `true` (it is termed logical indexing).
`A` and `logicalArray` must of course have the same size.

It is probably the fastest way of doing this operation in matlab.

For more information on indexing, see [matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this with an **arbitrary number of groups** (not just two as in your example), use [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with an a anoynmous function to collect the values in each group into a cell. To [preserve order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775147/2586922), `B` needs to be sorted first (and the same order needs to be applied to `A`):

```
[B_sort, ind_sort] = sort(B);
C = accumarray(B_sort.', A(ind_sort).', [], @(x){x.'});
```

This gives the result in a cell array:

```
>> C{1}
ans =
    10    16    28    36
>> C{2}
ans =
     5    22    32    44    49    56
```