# How can I delete unwanted zeros from a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like this :

```
 1     5     7     3     1     0
 1     8     1     0     0     0
 2     4     6     2     0     0
 2     9     10    2     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I want to change it to ...

```
 1     5     7     3     1     
 1     8     1         
 2     4     6     2     
 2     9     10    2
```

please help me

Comment: It's actually simple to write such a function

Comment: may you help me to write that function ?!  please

Comment: The later is not a matrix as some rows are a different length.  Will you be ok with the later being a cell array?

Comment: it's not matter.  The later, can be a cell array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output can be a cell array then something like this will do it.

```
% assume input is the first matrix
output = cell(size(input,1), 1);
for i = 1:length(output)
    output{i} = input(i, input(i, :) ~= 0);
end
```

What this does is create a cell array with the same number of rows as the original, then loops through the original finding the non-zero entries and keeping them.

You can keep just the non-zero values without retaining any of the row information with something like this:

```
output = input(input ~= 0);
```

This uses linear indexing and will flatten the matrix into a vector.

Comment: Wow.  thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For variety, here's a method that doesn't use loops:

```
in = [1 5 7 3 1 0; 1 8 1 0 0 0; 2 4 6 2 0 0; 2 9 10 2 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0]; % example data
[~, inds, vals] = find(in.'); % column indices and values of nonzeros of transposed input
result = accumarray(inds, vals, [size(in,1) 1], @(x){x.'}); % group by index
```

To understand how it works you may want to read the documentation of the [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) functions, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775147/2586922) to see why the transpose is needed.