# Find and indexing repeating elemnts in an array using Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array `A = [10 20 20 30 40 10 50];`

Is there any smart way to find and locate the repeating elements of this array ?

i.e.

```
10: [1 6]; 
20: [2 3];
```

I tried to use `unique` but I failed ...

Comment: *how* did you use `unique`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
% input array
A = [10 20 20 30 40 10 50];

% find unique elements (vals), and map values of A to indices (valsIdx)
[vals,~,valsIdx] = unique(A);

% group element locations by the above indices mapping
locs = accumarray(valsIdx, 1:numel(valsIdx), [], @(x){sort(x)});

% keep only values that are repeated
idx = cellfun(@numel, locs) > 1;
vals = vals(idx);
locs = locs(idx);
```

The result:

```
vals =
    10    20
locs = 
    [2x1 double]
    [2x1 double]

>> celldisp(locs)
locs{1} =
     1
     6
locs{2} =
     2
     3
```

Comment: Your solution works fine. What i dont understand is: How is the order of elements in `locs` defined? i inserted another `20` between `30 40` and the result for `locs{2}` is: `3 5 2` indices are right but it isn't sorted in any way i understand. Normally i would suspect it to be either sorted or inverse sorted. Mind explaining your code a bit`?

Comment: @TheMinion: done, I added some comments and fixed the locations to be always sorted. *(Side note: the order that comes out of `accumarray` is somewhat peculiar, read this post if you wanna find out more about it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17537523/97160)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is another:

```
>> A = [10 20 20 30 40 10 50];
>> S = sort(A);
>> S = arrayfun(@(x) [x find(x==A)], unique(S(diff(S)==0)), 'UniformOutput', false);
>> S{:}
ans =
    10     1     6
ans =
    20     2     3
```

If you don't have or want to use `arrayfun`, you can use a plain loop:

```
A = [10 20 20 20 30 40 10 50];

S = sort(A);
S = unique(S(diff(S)==0));

R = cell(size(S'));
for ii = 1:numel(S)
    R{ii} = [S(ii) find(A==S(ii))]; end
```

Comment: i am using an old version of Matlab. arrayfun is not supported

Comment: @user3270686: then use a plain loop :)

Comment: @user3270686: ...you'd be surprised.

Comment: @user3270686: Read for example, [Eric Raymond’s "Rule of Simplicity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Eric_Raymond.E2.80.99s_17_Unix_Rules).

Comment: @user3270686: how old is your version? `arrayfun` goes back to MATLAB 7 I think (from 10 years ago)!

Comment: @Amro: ... I suspect s/he just wanted a "smarter" solution than `arrayfun` :)

Comment: I did a bit of runtime testing. I used `A= round(rand(N,1)*M);`. Here i chose N 5000 and 50000. And played around with different values of M. Changing M results in more or less repeated values. For high M (few repeated values) @RodyOldenhuis's code was about one magnitude (factor 10) faster than @Amro's code. BUT for low M(many repeated values) Amro's code was 2 magnitudes faster. So both codes work and depending on the number of repeating values both codes have advantages regarding runtime. My vode works 2 (except he only returns the values not the according indices) and is allways between

Comment: the other 2 codes. :D For real high N values `>500k`my code runs fastest followed by @Amro and @RodyOldenhuis.

Comment: @TheMinion: Thank you for that. Do note that when loops are involved, runtimes depend strongly on MATLAB version. If the OP really has a MATLAB version as old as s/he suggests, loops should be avoided and Amro's solution will likely win in both cases (although I'm not quite sure if and how `accumarray` was implemented in that old a MATLAB...)

Comment: I didn't test the loop version but your first. Didn't even see that you posted the loop-solution as well :D

Comment: sorry but the answer is an empty matrix. Is this a Matlab version problem ? R = 

    [1x3 double]
    [1x4 double]

Comment: @user3270686: ...yes?

Comment: @TheMinion: I think the most important point is that even for `N` quite large, the computation times of all methods are in the order of tenths of seconds or less. Unless this functionality is needed inside the kernel of some super advanced number crunching algorithm that's being used to make say, accurate climate predictions 100 years in the future (so big data + very frequently called; in which case I'd advise a whole different language anyway), I'd say it's "fast enough", and we're really discussing micro-optimization here :)

Comment: yes ... R{1}= 10 1 7 but i don't know how to handle R. Is it a cell array ? R(1) gives what i wrote before

Comment: @user3270686: `R{1}(1)` is the value of the repeated element (in this case, 10) and `R{1}(2:end)` are the indices into `A` of where it's located. This is what you asked for right?

Comment: yes, i understood that. R{1}= 10 1 7 ,ok. But how can i store the elements of R{1} as variables ? i.e. x=1 y=7 etc

Comment: @user3270686: you want to assign the *indices* to variable names?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55180/discussion-between-user3270686-and-rody-oldenhuis).

Answer (score 1):

With `bsxfun` and `arrayfun`:

```
comp = tril(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), A(:).')); %'// compare all pairs of values
ind = find(sum(comp)>1); %// find repeated values
values = A(ind);
positions = arrayfun(@(n) find(comp(:,n).'.*(1:numel(A))), ind, 'uni', 0);
```

This gives:

```
>> values
values =
    10    20

>> positions{:}
ans =
     1     6

ans =
     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

**This solution only returns the values not the indices(location) of the values.**

```
%Your Data
A=[10 20 20 30 40 10 50]; 
%sorted Data
A_sorted=sort(A);
%find the duplicates
idx=find(diff(A_sorted)==0);
% the unique is needed when there are more than two duplicates.
result=unique(A_sorted(idx));
```

Comment: it detects the repeating values but i need also the indices of the initial array (i.e. A(1) and A(6), A(2) and A(3)

Comment: the other solutions do so. I could implement "their" solution into mine but that isn't really useful is it?