# Cumulative Summation in intervals - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, counter, reset, cumsum

Suppose I have 2 input vectors `x` and `reset` of the same size

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
reset = [0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

and an output `y` which is the cumulative sum of the elements in `x`. Whenever the value of resets corresponds to 1, the cumulative sum for the elements reset and start all over again just like below

```
y = [1 3 6 4 9 15]
```

How would I implement this in Matlab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach with `diff` and `cumsum` -

```
%// Setup few arrays: 
cx = cumsum(x)         %// Continuous Cumsumed version
reset_mask = reset==1  %// We want to create a logical array version of 
                       %// reset for use as logical indexing next up

%// Setup ID array of same size as input array and with differences between 
%// cumsumed values of each group placed at places where reset==1, 0s elsewhere
%// The groups are the islands of 0s and bordered at 1s in reset array.
id = zeros(size(reset))
diff_values = x(reset_mask) - cx(reset_mask)
id(reset_mask) = diff([0 diff_values])

%// "Under-compensate" the continuous cumsumed version cx with the 
%// "grouped diffed cumsum version" to get the desired output
y = cx + cumsum(id)
```

Comment: Hey, it works great but would you be able to explained this section of the code. id(reset==1) = diff([0 diff1(reset==1)])

Comment: @Alex Sure, coming up.

Comment: Thanks so much. Have been scratching my head on this for a while now.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, Yours was good alternative approach too! +1 already for you :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way:

```
result = accumarray(1+cumsum(reset(:)), x(:), [], @(t) {cumsum(t).'});
result = [result{:}];
```

This works because if the first input to [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is sorted, the order within each group of the second input is preserved (more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536558/fun-depending-on-order-of-subs-and-values-in-accumarray)).